# Get column names from a View using Eloquent

Tags: php, eloquent, slim, sqlsrv

I'm using Slim 3 with Eloquent and SQL Server.
Everything working fine.

Inside one of my Models I do:
`$this->getConnection()->getSchemaBuilder()->getColumnListing('table_name');`
and it gives me all the column names.

But when I do the same with a view: 
`$this->getConnection()->getSchemaBuilder()->getColumnListing('view_name')`
It gives me an empty array.

How can I get all the column names of a view using Eloquent?

Comment: Trust me, I have been there its a BAD idea. Been there :/

Comment: How can you teach something without explaining the reason why? @dexter

Comment: Thanks @dexter, I'm really interested in what you say. But could you be more specific?
What is a bad idea? Eloquent+views?

Comment: Lets say that you want to use pass the same data to controller than in that case you will run into problems as you were requesting some of the data in views instead of controller

Comment: Maybe I was not clear enough. I'm not talking about HTML views or twig views, I'm talking about views in SQL.